# How to forecast a time series which is generated by accumulating data of every five minutes and reset to 0 by the end of the day

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality

I am working with a time series data which is generated by accumulating data of every five minutes and reset to 0 by the end of the day. This is the scatter plot of the data.
[image]

It seems to not matching stationary assumption of traditional time series model, like arima or prophet. I used prophet to make a prediction. But the result shows the model performs badly near 0:00(the prediction near 0:00 is much higher than ground truth). Now I am trying to take the first difference of the data and put them to the model.
I wonder if there are any better models or solutions to fit this kind of data. Thank you in advance.

Here is the data

```
date,y1
2022/6/1 0:00,0.025534482
2022/6/1 0:05,0.046429771
2022/6/1 0:10,0.064790379
2022/6/1 0:15,0.081012709
2022/6/1 0:20,0.095594499
2022/6/1 0:25,0.10867563
2022/6/1 0:30,0.120589211
2022/6/1 0:35,0.131359718
2022/6/1 0:40,0.141249157
2022/6/1 0:45,0.15027672
2022/6/1 0:50,0.158615223
2022/6/1 0:55,0.166271768
2022/6/1 1:00,0.173405206
2022/6/1 1:05,0.179977549
2022/6/1 1:10,0.186100763
2022/6/1 1:15,0.191774297
2022/6/1 1:20,0.197073582
2022/6/1 1:25,0.20201983
2022/6/1 1:30,0.206675439
2022/6/1 1:35,0.211053594
2022/6/1 1:40,0.215199806
2022/6/1 1:45,0.219099168
2022/6/1 1:50,0.222804941
2022/6/1 1:55,0.226326407
2022/6/1 2:00,0.229719356
2022/6/1 2:05,0.23294937
2022/6/1 2:10,0.23606931
2022/6/1 2:15,0.239030527
2022/6/1 2:20,0.241902292
2022/6/1 2:25,0.244676688
2022/6/1 2:30,0.247365702
2022/6/1 2:35,0.249963747
2022/6/1 2:40,0.252500862
2022/6/1 2:45,0.254959202
2022/6/1 2:50,0.25736626
2022/6/1 2:55,0.259724518
2022/6/1 3:00,0.262082122
2022/6/1 3:05,0.264381356
2022/6/1 3:10,0.266691085
2022/6/1 3:15,0.268944194
2022/6/1 3:20,0.271193702
2022/6/1 3:25,0.273424729
2022/6/1 3:30,0.275683192
2022/6/1 3:35,0.277928638
2022/6/1 3:40,0.28021856
2022/6/1 3:45,0.282509016
2022/6/1 3:50,0.284866875
2022/6/1 3:55,0.287270278
2022/6/1 4:00,0.289788416
2022/6/1 4:05,0.292375615
2022/6/1 4:10,0.295078443
2022/6/1 4:15,0.297873333
2022/6/1 4:20,0.300828446
2022/6/1 4:25,0.303919033
2022/6/1 4:30,0.30724964
2022/6/1 4:35,0.310802389
2022/6/1 4:40,0.314621476
2022/6/1 4:45,0.318691539
2022/6/1 4:50,0.323120473
2022/6/1 4:55,0.327904184
2022/6/1 5:00,0.333225957
2022/6/1 5:05,0.33893107
2022/6/1 5:10,0.345142467
2022/6/1 5:15,0.351694261
2022/6/1 5:20,0.358803462
2022/6/1 5:25,0.3663703
2022/6/1 5:30,0.374595664
2022/6/1 5:35,0.383328176
2022/6/1 5:40,0.392608263
2022/6/1 5:45,0.402372529
2022/6/1 5:50,0.412758118
2022/6/1 5:55,0.423709094
2022/6/1 6:00,0.435703006
2022/6/1 6:05,0.448209021
2022/6/1 6:10,0.461432841
2022/6/1 6:15,0.475056288
2022/6/1 6:20,0.489298081
2022/6/1 6:25,0.503930283
2022/6/1 6:30,0.519437209
2022/6/1 6:35,0.535216196
2022/6/1 6:40,0.551623241
2022/6/1 6:45,0.568154532
2022/6/1 6:50,0.585209593
2022/6/1 6:55,0.602408015
2022/6/1 7:00,0.620523896
2022/6/1 7:05,0.638636481
2022/6/1 7:10,0.657085256
2022/6/1 7:15,0.675478656
2022/6/1 7:20,0.694088915
2022/6/1 7:25,0.712567258
2022/6/1 7:30,0.731359973
2022/6/1 7:35,0.749965795
2022/6/1 7:40,0.768787104
2022/6/1 7:45,0.787526231
2022/6/1 7:50,0.806570847
2022/6/1 7:55,0.825634673
2022/6/1 8:00,0.845198223
2022/6/1 8:05,0.864474623
2022/6/1 8:10,0.883815815
2022/6/1 8:15,0.902877566
2022/6/1 8:20,0.922032384
2022/6/1 8:25,0.940980789
2022/6/1 8:30,0.960062618
2022/6/1 8:35,0.978767556
2022/6/1 8:40,0.997476828
2022/6/1 8:45,1.015941461
2022/6/1 8:50,1.034342809
2022/6/1 8:55,1.05256305
2022/6/1 9:00,1.070826871
2022/6/1 9:05,1.088744727
2022/6/1 9:10,1.106557232
2022/6/1 9:15,1.124030603
2022/6/1 9:20,1.141344325
2022/6/1 9:25,1.158368095
2022/6/1 9:30,1.175214693
2022/6/1 9:35,1.191748833
2022/6/1 9:40,1.208255401
2022/6/1 9:45,1.224579817
2022/6/1 9:50,1.240867004
2022/6/1 9:55,1.257046678
2022/6/1 10:00,1.273395825
2022/6/1 10:05,1.289610829
2022/6/1 10:10,1.305705289
2022/6/1 10:15,1.32152168
2022/6/1 10:20,1.337282902
2022/6/1 10:25,1.352859059
2022/6/1 10:30,1.36848937
2022/6/1 10:35,1.384039167
2022/6/1 10:40,1.399573906
2022/6/1 10:45,1.415045591
2022/6/1 10:50,1.430587863
2022/6/1 10:55,1.446117214
2022/6/1 11:00,1.461780828
2022/6/1 11:05,1.477349044
2022/6/1 11:10,1.492966826
2022/6/1 11:15,1.508492236
2022/6/1 11:20,1.524109204
2022/6/1 11:25,1.539669336
2022/6/1 11:30,1.555287342
2022/6/1 11:35,1.570851767
2022/6/1 11:40,1.586524048
2022/6/1 11:45,1.602280944
2022/6/1 11:50,1.618276272
2022/6/1 11:55,1.634395663
2022/6/1 12:00,1.650662691
2022/6/1 12:05,1.666710689
2022/6/1 12:10,1.682869064
2022/6/1 12:15,1.699173473
2022/6/1 12:20,1.715788654
2022/6/1 12:25,1.732602683
2022/6/1 12:30,1.749544678
2022/6/1 12:35,1.766330329
2022/6/1 12:40,1.782935743
2022/6/1 12:45,1.799292064
2022/6/1 12:50,1.815467884
2022/6/1 12:55,1.83136214
2022/6/1 13:00,1.847118813
2022/6/1 13:05,1.862345516
2022/6/1 13:10,1.8771624
2022/6/1 13:15,1.891505544
2022/6/1 13:20,1.905546231
2022/6/1 13:25,1.919283718
2022/6/1 13:30,1.932869306
2022/6/1 13:35,1.946165253
2022/6/1 13:40,1.959217861
2022/6/1 13:45,1.972006885
2022/6/1 13:50,1.984698229
2022/6/1 13:55,1.997275341
2022/6/1 14:00,2.009924404
2022/6/1 14:05,2.022483329
2022/6/1 14:10,2.035010818
2022/6/1 14:15,2.04734124
2022/6/1 14:20,2.059585545
2022/6/1 14:25,2.07166073
2022/6/1 14:30,2.08369203
2022/6/1 14:35,2.09550248
2022/6/1 14:40,2.107220533
2022/6/1 14:45,2.118737696
2022/6/1 14:50,2.130186211
2022/6/1 14:55,2.14149119
2022/6/1 15:00,2.152912683
2022/6/1 15:05,2.164317458
2022/6/1 15:10,2.175668883
2022/6/1 15:15,2.186811764
2022/6/1 15:20,2.19787785
2022/6/1 15:25,2.20881139
2022/6/1 15:30,2.219702322
2022/6/1 15:35,2.230538891
2022/6/1 15:40,2.241405228
2022/6/1 15:45,2.252141076
2022/6/1 15:50,2.262853127
2022/6/1 15:55,2.273513011
2022/6/1 16:00,2.284236985
2022/6/1 16:05,2.294935134
2022/6/1 16:10,2.305656658
2022/6/1 16:15,2.316341568
2022/6/1 16:20,2.327015106
2022/6/1 16:25,2.337594953
2022/6/1 16:30,2.348214567
2022/6/1 16:35,2.358752614
2022/6/1 16:40,2.36946326
2022/6/1 16:45,2.380181959
2022/6/1 16:50,2.39099999
2022/6/1 16:55,2.401857165
2022/6/1 17:00,2.412911927
2022/6/1 17:05,2.423924057
2022/6/1 17:10,2.435102986
2022/6/1 17:15,2.446251055
2022/6/1 17:20,2.457492606
2022/6/1 17:25,2.46874521
2022/6/1 17:30,2.480152977
2022/6/1 17:35,2.491529094
2022/6/1 17:40,2.502930437
2022/6/1 17:45,2.514210014
2022/6/1 17:50,2.525516725
2022/6/1 17:55,2.536775905
2022/6/1 18:00,2.548002022
2022/6/1 18:05,2.559103477
2022/6/1 18:10,2.570191166
2022/6/1 18:15,2.581291432
2022/6/1 18:20,2.592476027
2022/6/1 18:25,2.60366573
2022/6/1 18:30,2.614960103
2022/6/1 18:35,2.626132592
2022/6/1 18:40,2.637345805
2022/6/1 18:45,2.648561795
2022/6/1 18:50,2.659914233
2022/6/1 18:55,2.671375254
2022/6/1 19:00,2.68314099
2022/6/1 19:05,2.694931697
2022/6/1 19:10,2.706786853
2022/6/1 19:15,2.718587192
2022/6/1 19:20,2.730497525
2022/6/1 19:25,2.742389089
2022/6/1 19:30,2.754380024
2022/6/1 19:35,2.766308449
2022/6/1 19:40,2.778221184
2022/6/1 19:45,2.790100066
2022/6/1 19:50,2.802060245
2022/6/1 19:55,2.814083652
2022/6/1 20:00,2.826278854
2022/6/1 20:05,2.838482531
2022/6/1 20:10,2.850715208
2022/6/1 20:15,2.863028648
2022/6/1 20:20,2.875459096
2022/6/1 20:25,2.887889632
2022/6/1 20:30,2.900528337
2022/6/1 20:35,2.913065267
2022/6/1 20:40,2.925526575
2022/6/1 20:45,2.937998897
2022/6/1 20:50,2.950539291
2022/6/1 20:55,2.963100386
2022/6/1 21:00,2.975728541
2022/6/1 21:05,2.988265304
2022/6/1 21:10,3.000839766
2022/6/1 21:15,3.013385859
2022/6/1 21:20,3.025974478
2022/6/1 21:25,3.038445196
2022/6/1 21:30,3.050901532
2022/6/1 21:35,3.063224093
2022/6/1 21:40,3.075414746
2022/6/1 21:45,3.087431681
2022/6/1 21:50,3.099313931
2022/6/1 21:55,3.111004077
2022/6/1 22:00,3.122657864
2022/6/1 22:05,3.134175202
2022/6/1 22:10,3.145446273
2022/6/1 22:15,3.156417918
2022/6/1 22:20,3.167122907
2022/6/1 22:25,3.177497211
2022/6/1 22:30,3.187607237
2022/6/1 22:35,3.197360314
2022/6/1 22:40,3.206780976
2022/6/1 22:45,3.215790815
2022/6/1 22:50,3.224457241
2022/6/1 22:55,3.232746728
2022/6/1 23:00,3.240710614
2022/6/1 23:05,3.248273047
2022/6/1 23:10,3.255463169
2022/6/1 23:15,3.2622672
2022/6/1 23:20,3.26873077
2022/6/1 23:25,3.274803851
2022/6/1 23:30,3.280558729
2022/6/1 23:35,3.285960538
2022/6/1 23:40,3.291080216
2022/6/1 23:45,3.295884437
2022/6/1 23:50,3.300427227
2022/6/1 23:55,3.304722824
2022/6/2 0:00,0.025899817
2022/6/2 0:05,0.047146404
2022/6/2 0:10,0.065573983
2022/6/2 0:15,0.081875263
2022/6/2 0:20,0.096543888
2022/6/2 0:25,0.109698263
2022/6/2 0:30,0.121677722
2022/6/2 0:35,0.13254524
2022/6/2 0:40,0.142503805
2022/6/2 0:45,0.151563441
2022/6/2 0:50,0.159903636
2022/6/2 0:55,0.167591097
2022/6/2 1:00,0.174709811
2022/6/2 1:05,0.181282689
2022/6/2 1:10,0.187440338
2022/6/2 1:15,0.193145259
2022/6/2 1:20,0.198488995
2022/6/2 1:25,0.203463813
2022/6/2 1:30,0.20816183
2022/6/2 1:35,0.212555163
2022/6/2 1:40,0.216712563
2022/6/2 1:45,0.220640655
2022/6/2 1:50,0.224394303
2022/6/2 1:55,0.227958999
2022/6/2 2:00,0.231392696
2022/6/2 2:05,0.234655198
2022/6/2 2:10,0.237803428
2022/6/2 2:15,0.240812488
2022/6/2 2:20,0.243721697
2022/6/2 2:25,0.246526443
2022/6/2 2:30,0.249239198
2022/6/2 2:35,0.251865039
2022/6/2 2:40,0.254430724
2022/6/2 2:45,0.256919525
2022/6/2 2:50,0.259352384
2022/6/2 2:55,0.26173183
2022/6/2 3:00,0.264097988
2022/6/2 3:05,0.266423941
2022/6/2 3:10,0.268744827
2022/6/2 3:15,0.27102427
2022/6/2 3:20,0.273299732
2022/6/2 3:25,0.275568298
2022/6/2 3:30,0.277844637
2022/6/2 3:35,0.280124024
2022/6/2 3:40,0.282451829
2022/6/2 3:45,0.284781429
2022/6/2 3:50,0.287172032
2022/6/2 3:55,0.289623868
2022/6/2 4:00,0.292185402
2022/6/2 4:05,0.294819168
2022/6/2 4:10,0.297583716
2022/6/2 4:15,0.300443551
2022/6/2 4:20,0.303461397
2022/6/2 4:25,0.306645858
2022/6/2 4:30,0.310067984
2022/6/2 4:35,0.313699045
2022/6/2 4:40,0.317621143
2022/6/2 4:45,0.321801136
2022/6/2 4:50,0.326345674
2022/6/2 4:55,0.331245237
2022/6/2 5:00,0.336701025
2022/6/2 5:05,0.342562578
2022/6/2 5:10,0.348921038
2022/6/2 5:15,0.355630652
2022/6/2 5:20,0.362879127
2022/6/2 5:25,0.370583427
2022/6/2 5:30,0.37891142
2022/6/2 5:35,0.387713616
2022/6/2 5:40,0.397137103
2022/6/2 5:45,0.406986002
2022/6/2 5:50,0.417457587
2022/6/2 5:55,0.428486532
2022/6/2 6:00,0.440592745
2022/6/2 6:05,0.453175299
2022/6/2 6:10,0.466506137
2022/6/2 6:15,0.480220329
2022/6/2 6:20,0.494550521
2022/6/2 6:25,0.509232912
2022/6/2 6:30,0.524782733
2022/6/2 6:35,0.540623879
2022/6/2 6:40,0.557054234
2022/6/2 6:45,0.573628205
2022/6/2 6:50,0.590682045
2022/6/2 6:55,0.607798037
2022/6/2 7:00,0.625817666
2022/6/2 7:05,0.643759455
2022/6/2 7:10,0.66197545
2022/6/2 7:15,0.680080589
2022/6/2 7:20,0.698430711
2022/6/2 7:25,0.716588984
2022/6/2 7:30,0.734904758
2022/6/2 7:35,0.752996953
2022/6/2 7:40,0.771208136
2022/6/2 7:45,0.789248865
2022/6/2 7:50,0.807419611
2022/6/2 7:55,0.82564654
2022/6/2 8:00,0.844232035
2022/6/2 8:05,0.862540946
2022/6/2 8:10,0.880858141
2022/6/2 8:15,0.898974213
2022/6/2 8:20,0.917111402
2022/6/2 8:25,0.934988445
2022/6/2 8:30,0.952928885
2022/6/2 8:35,0.970614534
2022/6/2 8:40,0.988234465
2022/6/2 8:45,1.005627249
2022/6/2 8:50,1.022980985
2022/6/2 8:55,1.0401479
2022/6/2 9:00,1.057367079
2022/6/2 9:05,1.074349766
2022/6/2 9:10,1.091165367
2022/6/2 9:15,1.107686029
2022/6/2 9:20,1.123962394
2022/6/2 9:25,1.139905586
2022/6/2 9:30,1.155676759
2022/6/2 9:35,1.171124487
2022/6/2 9:40,1.186524381
2022/6/2 9:45,1.201755281
2022/6/2 9:50,1.217007361
2022/6/2 9:55,1.232178049
2022/6/2 10:00,1.247491754
2022/6/2 10:05,1.262689448
2022/6/2 10:10,1.277837799
2022/6/2 10:15,1.292704154
2022/6/2 10:20,1.307581347
2022/6/2 10:25,1.322323391
2022/6/2 10:30,1.337039795
2022/6/2 10:35,1.351655262
2022/6/2 10:40,1.366287353
2022/6/2 10:45,1.380874027
2022/6/2 10:50,1.395551526
2022/6/2 10:55,1.410211484
2022/6/2 11:00,1.424957455
2022/6/2 11:05,1.439631003
2022/6/2 11:10,1.454363743
2022/6/2 11:15,1.468936491
2022/6/2 11:20,1.483553746
2022/6/2 11:25,1.498017099
2022/6/2 11:30,1.512573495
2022/6/2 11:35,1.527082711
2022/6/2 11:40,1.541715241
2022/6/2 11:45,1.556407064
2022/6/2 11:50,1.571307751
2022/6/2 11:55,1.586310731
2022/6/2 12:00,1.601482944
2022/6/2 12:05,1.616503345
2022/6/2 12:10,1.63159205
2022/6/2 12:15,1.646787701
2022/6/2 12:20,1.662272953
2022/6/2 12:25,1.677875349
2022/6/2 12:30,1.693627944
2022/6/2 12:35,1.709289699
2022/6/2 12:40,1.724803847
2022/6/2 12:45,1.740015643
2022/6/2 12:50,1.755017505
2022/6/2 12:55,1.769758744
2022/6/2 13:00,1.784371426
2022/6/2 13:05,1.79854572
2022/6/2 13:10,1.812315935
2022/6/2 13:15,1.825663531
2022/6/2 13:20,1.838776823
2022/6/2 13:25,1.85162056
2022/6/2 13:30,1.864361159
2022/6/2 13:35,1.876867892
2022/6/2 13:40,1.889157493
2022/6/2 13:45,1.901232566
2022/6/2 13:50,1.913229878
2022/6/2 13:55,1.92515021
2022/6/2 14:00,1.93719791
2022/6/2 14:05,1.949088779
2022/6/2 14:10,1.960881952
2022/6/2 14:15,1.97248808
2022/6/2 14:20,1.984065837
2022/6/2 14:25,1.99548674
2022/6/2 14:30,2.006894778
2022/6/2 14:35,2.018072646
2022/6/2 14:40,2.029181834
2022/6/2 14:45,2.040136482
2022/6/2 14:50,2.05106224
2022/6/2 14:55,2.061890805
2022/6/2 15:00,2.07296294
2022/6/2 15:05,2.083952422
2022/6/2 15:10,2.094854311
2022/6/2 15:15,2.105565006
2022/6/2 15:20,2.116202488
2022/6/2 15:25,2.126712962
2022/6/2 15:30,2.137243308
2022/6/2 15:35,2.147705349
2022/6/2 15:40,2.158177812
2022/6/2 15:45,2.168630787
2022/6/2 15:50,2.179098598
2022/6/2 15:55,2.189519357
2022/6/2 16:00,2.200042543
2022/6/2 16:05,2.210512804
2022/6/2 16:10,2.221014428
2022/6/2 16:15,2.231477243
2022/6/2 16:20,2.241977973
2022/6/2 16:25,2.252393425
2022/6/2 16:30,2.26286011
2022/6/2 16:35,2.273225325
2022/6/2 16:40,2.283662076
2022/6/2 16:45,2.294054871
2022/6/2 16:50,2.304550757
2022/6/2 16:55,2.315040051
2022/6/2 17:00,2.32559409
2022/6/2 17:05,2.336116312
2022/6/2 17:10,2.346689248
2022/6/2 17:15,2.357281578
2022/6/2 17:20,2.36799058
2022/6/2 17:25,2.378690597
2022/6/2 17:30,2.389436709
2022/6/2 17:35,2.400076354
2022/6/2 17:40,2.410723005
2022/6/2 17:45,2.421412129
2022/6/2 17:50,2.432203657
2022/6/2 17:55,2.443041367
2022/6/2 18:00,2.453923425
2022/6/2 18:05,2.464636841
2022/6/2 18:10,2.47530018
2022/6/2 18:15,2.485960207
2022/6/2 18:20,2.496693885
2022/6/2 18:25,2.507438536
2022/6/2 18:30,2.518223879
2022/6/2 18:35,2.528967038
2022/6/2 18:40,2.539704172
2022/6/2 18:45,2.550427028
2022/6/2 18:50,2.561227159
2022/6/2 18:55,2.572075221
2022/6/2 19:00,2.583060178
2022/6/2 19:05,2.594008728
2022/6/2 19:10,2.604998873
2022/6/2 19:15,2.615937025
2022/6/2 19:20,2.626966265
2022/6/2 19:25,2.637963265
2022/6/2 19:30,2.64908827
2022/6/2 19:35,2.66016489
2022/6/2 19:40,2.671304388
2022/6/2 19:45,2.682364903
2022/6/2 19:50,2.693545492
2022/6/2 19:55,2.704789142
2022/6/2 20:00,2.716207451
2022/6/2 20:05,2.727569068
2022/6/2 20:10,2.739004383
2022/6/2 20:15,2.750468723
2022/6/2 20:20,2.762068163
2022/6/2 20:25,2.773648108
2022/6/2 20:30,2.785311184
2022/6/2 20:35,2.796888606
2022/6/2 20:40,2.808518277
2022/6/2 20:45,2.820117765
2022/6/2 20:50,2.831786874
2022/6/2 20:55,2.843453374
2022/6/2 21:00,2.855227338
2022/6/2 21:05,2.866980816
2022/6/2 21:10,2.878745052
2022/6/2 21:15,2.890491707
2022/6/2 21:20,2.902208994
2022/6/2 21:25,2.913830165
2022/6/2 21:30,2.925455981
2022/6/2 21:35,2.936935715
2022/6/2 21:40,2.948316317
2022/6/2 21:45,2.959552864
2022/6/2 21:50,2.970729686
2022/6/2 21:55,2.981771663
2022/6/2 22:00,2.992820424
2022/6/2 22:05,3.003794592
2022/6/2 22:10,3.014655677
2022/6/2 22:15,3.025274317
2022/6/2 22:20,3.035702649
2022/6/2 22:25,3.045851739
2022/6/2 22:30,3.055737674
2022/6/2 22:35,3.065318974
2022/6/2 22:40,3.074626378
2022/6/2 22:45,3.083593329
2022/6/2 22:50,3.092238
2022/6/2 22:55,3.100515477
2022/6/2 23:00,3.108488701
2022/6/2 23:05,3.116148614
2022/6/2 23:10,3.123475018
2022/6/2 23:15,3.130436414
2022/6/2 23:20,3.137095863
2022/6/2 23:25,3.143376163
2022/6/2 23:30,3.149360598
2022/6/2 23:35,3.155014604
2022/6/2 23:40,3.160408153
2022/6/2 23:45,3.165486517
2022/6/2 23:50,3.170322715
2022/6/2 23:55,3.174907203
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your data is seasonal: you have $24\times 12=288$ buckets per day, and your data repeats essentially daily, so you need to specify a season length attribute (AKA frequency) of 288. Then standard methods should work nicely.

The data you posted contained only two full seasonal cycles, and many packages will not fit a seasonal model unless the data contain more than two cycles, so I simply pasted two copies of your data together for the analyses below.

The simplest method would simply be a seasonal naive forecast: just forecast the last observation in the same time bucket. If you cast this as SARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,0)[288], you even get prediction intervals:

[image: seasonal naive forecast]

Another simple possibility would be to take means per time bucket. I don't think there is a built-in function to do this, though.

Next, SARIMA (seasonal ARIMA) has major problems with "long" seasonalities, and a season length of 288 definitely qualifies. It took my R quite some time to fit a rather straightforward SARIMA(0,1,0)(0,1,0)[288] model:

[image: ARIMA forecast]

Another method I like using is seasonal exponential smoothing, but this will be highly unstable for your seasonal length, so `forecast::ets` rightly refuses to do this.

Finally, you can use a seasonal decomposition method like STLF:

[image: STLF forecast]

You may want to take a look at *Forecasting: Principles and Practice* by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman, [2nd ed.](https://otexts.org/fpp2/) or [3rd ed.](https://otexts.org/fpp3/).

R code:

```
timeseries <- scan(what="character",sep=",")
date,y1
2022/6/1 0:00,0.025534482
2022/6/1 0:05,0.046429771
2022/6/1 0:10,0.064790379
...

library(forecast)
yy_2 <- ts(rep(as.numeric(timeseries[seq(2,length(timeseries),by=2)]),2),start=c(1,1),frequency=24*12)

plot(snaive(yy_2,h=24*12))

model_arima <- auto.arima(yy_2)
summary(model_arima)
plot(forecast(model_arima,h=24*12))

model_es <- ets(yy_2)

model_stlf <- stlf(yy_2)
summary(model_stlf)
plot(forecast(model_stlf,horizon=24*12))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will try to adjust the season length to fit data. BTW, the data is actually multiple seasonal(daily partten/weekly pattern/annual pattern). Maybe another method should be used to deal with this issue.

Comment: We have a [tag:multiple-seasonalities] tag. Its [tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-seasonalities/info) contains pointers to possible forecasting algorithms. If you specify the seasonal periods correctly, I would assume they should work fine for your data.

Comment: Hi Stephan. I wonder if you could give some suggestion on this question [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598237/how-to-calculate-the-forecast-interval-for-time-series-prediction-obtained-by-do), which is the extension of this question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Another, more heuristic approach here is to try to model the *changes* in `y1`, rather than the actual values, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df = clipr::read_clip_tbl(sep = ',') # Read data from clipboard
df = df %>%
  mutate(date = parse_date_time(date, '%y/%m/%d %R')
         day = floor_date(date, 'days'),
         time = difftime(date, day, units = 'hours')) %>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  mutate(delta = y1 - lag(y1)) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(df, aes(time, delta, color = factor(day))) + geom_path()
```

[image]