# How to calculate the forecast interval for time series prediction obtained by doing seasonal differencing before fitting arima

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality, prediction-interval, differencing

Here is the link of my previous question. [How to forecast a time series which is generated by accumulating data of every five minutes and reset to 0 by the end of the day](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579846/how-to-forecast-a-time-series-which-is-generated-by-accumulating-data-of-every-f/579863#579863)

I am working with a seasonal data of which period is 288. Thanks to @Stephan Kolassa, I did find sarima can fit the data well. But since the prediction would be running on an online service, sarima seems to be quite time consuming. So I manually do the seasonal differencing, and fit the data with non-seasonal arima.

Here are the steps:

Step1: calculate $Y_{t\_sdiff} = (Y_t - Y_{t-288})-(Y_{t-1} - Y_{t-1-288})$ (set some outliers as 0)

Step2: fit  $Y_{t\_sdiff} $ with non-seansonal arima

Step3: predict $Y_{t+1\_sdiff} $

Step4: calculate $Y_{t+1}=Y_{t+1\_sdiff}+Y_{t+1-288}+(Y_{t} - Y_{t-288})$

The result shows that the precedure above works also well, the point estimate is quite close to the truth. But I also want to obtain the  forecast interval of prediction. So, I calculate the it based on the formula in step4, which means that the variance of prediction mainly comes from $Y_{t+1\_sdiff}$. After reviewing the result, I found there must be some wrong right here. Because the magnitude of forecast interval is much more smaller than Y. But I cann't figure out how to get the right forecast interval.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want a forecast interval / prediction interval, not a confidence interval. These are not the same. The first considers realizations of a random variable while the latter considers parameter values. If you indeed are interested in a forecast interval, please edit the post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me~I will fix it